# How can I listen for UILabel content changes?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to listen the content changes in the UIlabel and prevent it from changing when its length is greater than 7. What should I do? I tried set / get / willset / didset. It seems that it can't meet my needs

I wrote a simple demo ，When I press the button, add a number to display area. I don't want his length to exceed my expectations

[image]

In my real project, I'm developing a calculator
What I can think of is to judge the length of displayValue, but doing so will make my code wordy

Comment: We would need more detail about how this is set up (ideally, some code). `UILabel` doesn't just mysteriously change its own content, so you must have access to the call sites where you're mutating the contents. Unless perhaps you're talking about trying to subclass it? Please include the relevant code.

Comment: UILabel or UITextField? UILabel can't be interactively changed from the user since it's a label and it's static or programmatically changeable.

Comment: I have updated my specific requirements. Please have a look ，thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**didSet** can help you better.
add this code in line number 6 in your code.

```
var displayValue: String = "" {
    didSet {
        if displayValue.count <= 7 {
            customLabel.text = displayValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your action function, you need to just do it.

```
@IBAction func clickBtn( _ sender: Any) {
    displayValue = displayValue + "0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting the characters inside a label you use the count method in the text property like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    testLabel.text = "duck"
    print(testLabel.text.count) //return 4
}
```

For user action you can't use the UILabel since it's not user interactive, you have to use the UITextField and connect to him an UIAction or explain us better what you want to do.

Comment: I have updated my specific requirements. Please have a look ，thanks very much